# How to extract desired results from different columns

Tags: mysql-5.6

In order to conserve space and eliminate duplicates, I have the following table of distances between locations:

```
patientIDa | patientIDb | distance |  
1          | 2          | 4.5      |  
1          | 3          | 2.8      |  
1          | 4          | 1.3      |  
1          | 5          | 0.9      |  
2          | 3          | 2.0      |  
2          | 4          | 5.3      |  
2          | 5          | 4.4      |  
3          | 4          | 4.4      |  
3          | 5          | 3.7      |  
4          | 5          | 4.5      |
```

I run the following query to get the three closest distances to patient #3:

```
Select * From Distances Where (patientIDa=3 OR patientIDb=3)
Order By distance
Limit 3;
```

Result set:

```
patientIDa  patientIDb  distance  
2           | 3         | 2.0  
1           | 3         | 2.8  
3           | 5         | 3.7
```

How would I go about extracting the corresponding patientIDx's (2, 1, 5), as they are in different columns?
Running MySQL 5.6 on aws.
Apologies on the formatting.

As an aside, is this bad design to begin with? I'm fairly new at DB tech.

Comment: It looks like you have done something to assure that `patientIDa < patientIDb`.  There is, there can be [1,2], but not [2,1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT patientIDa, patientIDb, distance 
    FROM Distances 
    WHERE patientIDa=3 
UNION ALL
    SELECT patientIDb, patientIDa, distance  
    FROM Distances 
    WHERE patientIDb=3
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: What do you think of what I said about the performance implications of querying table twice for the `UNION`?

Comment: @Akina, thank you this works. though is in conflict with with the advice from [MySQLtutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) which states "... the number and the **orders** of columns that appear in **all** SELECT statements must be the same".  It is apparently incorrect.

Comment: @KenGustafson *".. the number and the orders of columns that appear in all SELECT statements must be the same"* You have not understood this phrase. It means that datatypes must match for all fields with the same positional number in output lists of separate subqueries included into UNION query. Fieldnames doesn't matter. And I doubt that `patientIDa` and `patientIDb` have different datatypes. PS. The only document you must refer to is official [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  UNION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), any another is for consulting purposes only.

Comment: @Akina, thanks for clearing up the positional / datatype structure of the query.  And thanks for the official document link, yes the only one to reference!

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to avoid a `UNION` - not certain of performance here, but this **might** be better (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=60da65aba840cdce4a980c435c9617b6)) - you don't have to query the table twice as for @Akina's query! You might want to check with a large dataset.

Create and populate table:

```
CREATE table pat_dis
(
  p1  INT,
  p2  INT,
  dis FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO pat_dis VALUES
( 1, 2, 1.1),
( 1, 5, 1.5),
( 2, 3, 2.0),  
( 1, 3, 2.8),
( 3, 5, 3.7),
( 8, 3, 9.9),
( 4, 7, 0.1); -- << extra record no paitent 3 and small distance
```

And then run this query:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN LEAST(p1, p2) < 3 THEN p1
     WHEN GREATEST (p1, p2 > 3) THEN  p2
  END AS patient,
  dis AS distance
FROM pat_dis
WHERE (p1 = 3 OR p2 = 3)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 3;
```

Result:

```
patient     distance
      2            2
      1          2.8
      5          3.7
```

Et voilà! Following the OP's comment on my elementary error, with the new `WHERE` clause, this is now the correct answer even **if** there are patients with a shorter distance between them but neither of whom is patient 3. Both fiddles have been amended.

As an aside, I would recommend that you upgrade to version 8 of MySQL. Apart from all sorts of goodies like [`Common Table Expressions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) and [`Window functions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), you get [`CHECK` constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) which allow you to write this (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=011a9a6f7e8964b0aeff47e60d7da69c)):

```
CREATE table pat_dis
(
  p1  INT,
  p2  INT, 
  CONSTRAINT patient_not_same CHECK (p1 != p2),  -- version 8 - new line!
  dis FLOAT
);
```

Now try:

```
INSERT INTO pat_dis VALUES (3, 3, 3.6); -- cannot insert identical patients!
                                        -- see same line in 1st fiddle.
```

Result:

```
Check constraint 'patient_not_same' is violated.
```

Comment: thank you.  This got me thinking it should work, though when I ran the query on the original table it produced the three shortest distances overall, not just for patientID=3.  I added two rows to the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b33b83aa2fc12be90061b492a3ea8f35) which demonstrates as much. Not sure what's going on, but thanks for the v8 tip, although AWS is stuck on 5.6 for their RDS serverless stack :(

Comment: Doh! (hits forehead with open palm á la Homer Simpson). Schoolboy error - comes from doing SQL late at night! :-) A simple `WHERE (p1 = 3 OR p2 = 3)` eliminates this problem!